# Best way to order your js files in your HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, scripting

In my project i'm referring so many js files but due to order sometimes i get object reference error ..

```
<head>
    <!-- -------------CSS FILE REFERENCE START------------------------------------------------------------>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Scripts/jquery.jqGrid-4.5.2/css/Custom.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Scripts/jquery.jqGrid-4.5.2/css/jquery.ui.theme.css" type="text/css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Scripts/jquery.jqGrid-4.5.2/css/ui.jqgrid.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../styles/MYCSS1.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../styles/MYCSS2.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Scripts/CalendarControl.css"  type="text/css" />
    <link href="../styles/jqgridstyles/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../styles/jqgridstyles/jqGridPoc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../styles/jqgridstyles/printelement.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!----------- CSS FILE REFERENCE END------------------------------------------------------------------>
    <!-- -------------JS FILE REFERENCE START------------------------------------------------------------>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.jqGrid-4.5.2/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.jqGrid-4.5.2/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/styles/jquery.jqGrid.src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/CalendarControl.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/MaintainConfigData/A1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/ViewAuditErrorInfo/T1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/MaintainConfigData/D1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/MaintainConfigData/D2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/MaintainConfigData/D3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/MaintainConfigData/A2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/MaintainConfigData/D4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/MaintainConfigData/D5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/MaintainConfigData/D6.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/MaintainConfigData/D7.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/TestHarness/T2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/ViewAuditErrorInfo/DateTimepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/CD1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jsonparsing.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="../Scripts/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    <script src="../Scripts/jqgridutility/jqGrid_Demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jqgridutility/printelem.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/JScript1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jqgridutility/Utils.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- -------------JS FILE REFERENCE END------------------------------------------------------------>
    <style type="text/css">
        .ui-dialog-title {
            font-weight: bold !important;
            font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial !important;
            font-size: 12px !important;
        }

        .ui-dialog-titlebar {
            color: #FFFFFF !important;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: bold !important;
            height: 16px;
            background-color: #9A9AB3 !important;
            text-align: left;
            padding-left: 5px;
            padding-right: 0px;
            padding-top: 3px;
            padding-bottom: 3px;
            display: block;
            border-top-left-radius: 0px !important;
            border-top-right-radius: 0px !important;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 0px !important;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 0px !important;
        }

        .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
            visibility: hidden;
        }

        .ui-state-default .ui-icon {
            /* background-color:white;
            background-image:url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png);*/
        }

        .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content {
            overflow: inherit !important;
            font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial !important;
            font-size: 12px !important;
        }

        .ui-dialog-titlebar ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix {
        }

        .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {
            padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
        }
        .ui-jqdialog-content, .ui-jqdialog .ui-jqdialog-content 
        {
            background-color:White;
            font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial !important;
            font-size: 12px !important;
        }
        .ui-jqdialog-content input.FormElement 
        {
            color: black;
        }
    </style>
    <title>MY WebApp</title>
</head>
```

I just want to know is there any best practice or any trick to avoid such errors ...when i place highcharts.js at bottom it gives me error but when i comment it and shift it up its working

Comment: Its good one ...but can anyone give any experts view http://store.redstage.com/blog/2012/07/24/how-to-properly-include-custom-css-and-js-files-in-magento/

Comment: JS <script> tag will executed immediately so i think that's dependency issue if it is placed not in correct sequence

Comment: What to do if i don't know the exact order of dependency.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-requirejs-for-effective-javascript-module-loading/

Comment: @RahulChowdhury: *"What to do if i don't know the exact order of dependency."* Then find out. You're responsible for what you put on the pages you author. If you don't know what a script relies on, find out.

Answer (score 1):

[Best practice](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#num_http) is to combine your script files, minify/compress the result, and have only one `script` tag. (And [at the end](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom), not in `head`.) But that still leaves the question of order (the order in which you combine them).

Fundamentally, be aware of what your individual scripts require (e.g., A relies on B, so B must be before A), and put the files in the order required.

In a complex deployment, you might look at using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org) or similar, which can help automate satisfying the prerequisites of individual scripts.

Comment: Thanks man..but the example you give A depends on B then put B before A its good for 1 to 1 dependency ...but what about 1 to many dependency i mean a complex scenario ...what even if i dont know the exact dependency ..And can you explan a bit require.js

Comment: @RahulChowdhury: I very much doubt you'll run into circular dependencies (A needs B, B needs C, but C needs A), so again, it's a matter of knowing what you're putting on your page, knowing what it relies on, and putting things in the right order. If you have multiple scripts all relying on another (typical example: jQuery plugins rely on jQuery), just make sure the one they rely on comes first. Think in terms of one thing building on another. Re RequireJS, it's a module system for resolving these things automatically, but it introduces its own complexity. See the site for details.

Answer (score 0):

Scripts must be loaded in order they are required. If you are getting errors in script load,keep pushing the script up in the order.

For best practices, you must bundle and minify scripts-
Check [Cassette](http://getcassette.net/) out.

Answer (score -2):

You will find a great article here:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/24-javascript-best-practices-for-beginners--net-5399

Also i recommend minifying your JS & CSS files